# Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcku`

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to get a React Native app I made to work on android. It is giving me an error when I build the project, however: it says that `Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcku.` (I had several other errors before this one, but those were resolved.)

Just in case, here is my Android Studio:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

And here is my gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

android.enableR8 = false
android.enableD8 = true
# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1
```

Thanks.